# execute a javascript function if the user is not active on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm looking for a javascript or jQuery function to execute my function newalert() if the user is not active on the page, ( maybe with some event to check the cursor position or something like this )

i will make it auto check using settimeout , i just want the function to check the availability of user like in gmail chat, when receiving a new IM and you are not watching the gmail page, it plays a bleep sound.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `window.onblur` event, or you can have a timer that is running continuously and when the mouse position is the same for x amount of milliseconds, execute the function.

Example:

```
var lastX, lastY = 0;
var act_timeout = null;
function doAction() {
   alert( 'not active' );
   return false;
}
function move( e ) {
   if( e.clientY == lastY && e.clientX == lastX ) {
       act_timeout = setTimeout( doAction, 5000 );
       return;
   }
   lastX = e.clientX;
   lastY = e.clientY;
   act_timeout = clearTimeout( act_timeout );
}
window.onmousemove = move;
window.onblur = doAction;
```

Comment: i tried it, but it's works only one time, and the page seems like loading content when executing the alert.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You first need to identify what it means for the user to be active and in active.  Obvious signs of inactivity include the window `blur` event, but you might want to look at these others

- Window `blur` event
- No mouse activity: no scrolling, clicks, or movement
- No keyboard activity

A good list of mouse events and their caveats are provided at [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html).

Once you determine what it means to be inactive, you can clear your timer when the opposing events occur (mouse is moved/clicked/scrolled, window is focused, keyboard event is a received, etc).